# Is it true that women's rights organizations completely ignore the plight of Israeli women targeted by Hamas?

Tags: israel-hamas-war, united-nations

According to this source

> as Hamas targeted Israeli women and children for slaughter and abduction in their war against Israel, there has been near silence from international human rights and women’s rights organizations.
> Israeli women’s rights activists say that “there is a clear double standard” as they struggle to obtain a mere recognition of these atrocities. ([CTech](https://www.calcalistech.com/ctechnews/article/hjxrkypma))

The article mentions Na'ama Levy, a 19 year old Israeli girl kidnapped by Hamas.

Blogger matanperetz also has similar claims "'Whatever happened to believe all women?'" ([here](https://www.instagram.com/reel/CzgsiHwth05/?igshid=MTgzenA3MDZhYmllYQ%3D%3D))

Are those claims true? Do the organizations for international women's rights ignore those victims?

Comment: to clarify i specifically ask about women's plight and organizations for women such as UN women. it's clear to me that there's a lot of commentary about the war.

Comment: This is like asking why anti-abortion groups are ignoring all the unborn babies being killed in Gaza.

Comment: @HannoverFist: well, you made me curious. Never say never https://www.redletterchristians.org/war-abortion-pro-life-christians-care-gaza/

Answer (score 2):

"Near silence" is [debatable](https://www.amnesty.org/en/latest/news/2023/10/israel-palestinian-armed-groups-must-be-held-accountable-for-deliberate-civilian-killings-abductions-and-indiscriminate-attacks/).

> Hamas and other Palestinian armed groups flagrantly violated international law and displayed a chilling disregard for human life by carrying out cruel and brutal crimes including mass summary killings, hostage-taking, and launching indiscriminate rocket attacks into Israel, Amnesty International said today.

Etc.

AFAICT, pro-Israeli NGOs have been [railing](https://www.algemeiner.com/2023/10/25/human-rights-watch-demonizing-israel-in-wake-hamas-terror-onslaught-ngo-report/) against those orgs since then allegedly for their “demonization and tokenism” against Israel for the subsequent stances on the Israeli armed response. But mostly against HRW it seems, which saw fit to remind [at length](https://www.hrw.org/the-day-in-human-rights/2023/10/09) of the Israeli violations of human rights on their Oct 9 position piece.

That's probably also related to later stuff HRW said [like](https://www.hrw.org/news/2023/10/19/international-humanitarian-law-applies-all-states)

> Fast forward 18 months from Russia’s all-out invasion of Ukraine to the new escalation of hostilities in Israel and Palestine. On the weekend of October 7 and 8, the United States and European countries quickly and rightly denounced the brutal Hamas-led attacks against Israel in which Palestinian armed groups killed more than 1,400 men, women, and children and took almost 200 hostages. They also quickly and rightly called for those responsible to be held to account and for hostages to be released.
>
> But the reaction from Washington and – with a few exceptions – from European capitals to Israel’s actions in Gaza since October 7 has been muted. Where is the clear condemnation of the cruel tightening of the 16-year closure of Gaza that amounts to collective punishment, a war crime?

... effectively comparing Israel's actions with Russia's. Which TASS [relished on](https://tass.com/world/1694065), I might add. (They didn't mention there Russia [banned](https://www.hrw.org/news/2022/04/08/russia-government-shuts-down-human-rights-watch-office) the group along with Amnesty International.)

Anyhow, pro-Israeli NGOs contend that the *volume* of Israel condemnation by HRW etc. far exceeds what is due, and that in contrast Hamas' deeds should be the focus. Generally speaking, those [two] organizations have long irked Israel and friends, e.g. some US Republican politicians [walked out](https://www.algemeiner.com/2023/06/22/disgusted-congressional-human-rights-chair-announces-boycott-of-amnesty-international-human-rights-watch-over-israel-treatment/) in June when those organizations were testifying. (The beef was over words like 'apartheid' then, it seems.)

That goes for "international human rights [...] organizations". As for "women’s rights organizations", I'll let someone else figure out which are the notable ones worth checking out in this context.

Comment: the question is specifically about women's rights organisations. obe good example would be UN women.

Comment: @Angriffsreiher: why? I don't expect anything UN run to be very far from UN's position overall, and we know that the amendment to condemn Hamas failed there (due to 2/3 threshold needed). Never heard of UN women before, but on a quick look their board is dominated by Africa and Asia, and most of those countries voted against condemning Hamas https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UN_Women#Structure_and_functioning

Comment: @Angriffsreiher: an yeah [apparently](https://isgap.org/flashpoint/response-to-hamas-horror-shows-the-feminist-movement-has-lost-its-moral-compass/) UN Women put out a statement that didn't mention Hamas, just like the UNGA resolution. OTOH it just said it "condemns the attacks on civilians in Israel and the Occupied Palestinian Territories and is deeply alarmed by the devastating impact on civilians including women and girls". Big "surprise" there. I'll see if I can find their actual statement.

Comment: FWTW found https://www.womenforwomen.org/node/2314 which is similarly worded.